# How can we transfer the modules such as networkx, OSMnx , etc installed in one computer to another

Tags: qgis, python, networkx

I have multiple computers with QGIS installed on them. I am creating a custom plugin for QGIS using Python. I have installed the modules such as Networkx, OSMnx, pip, matplotlib etc. in my computer/laptop I am working on. Now I am moving to another PC, is there any easy way to transfer all the required modules to the other PC?

I tried to copy the user profile folder from one computer and paste it in another, but it doesn't transfer the required modules.

Comment: It really depends how you installed those modules. So how did you install those modules?

Comment: with the help of pip install, but some modules came with OSGeo4W, so mainly i want these modules, the ones in OSGeo4w , so how do i get them

Comment: Could try this? Open a cmd window in the Scripts folder in your python install on your new computer then use `pip install -U xxx` where xxx is the module.

Answer (score 1):

Default path for python modules, installed with QGIS (my version is 3.16) is not user profile, but:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\Python37\Lib\site-packages
```

You can copy the folders with the modules you need from this path to the same path on the client computer

Comment: I downloaded OSGeo4W in my computer and mainly the modules are stored in it. So actually I want to get the exact modules from my computer to the other computer i am working on. It has modules like GDAL, networkx, fiona, etc. So how to do it?